# How to compare lists length Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new at Prolog and i was trying to solve some exercises and I found this one twice_as_long(L1,L2) that succeeds if the list L2 is twice as long as the list L1.

#### Do NOT compute the lengths of the lists.

```
twice_as_long([],[]).
true.

?- twice_as_long([a],[1,2]).
true.

?- twice_as_long([a,b],X).
X = [_G328, _G331, _G334, _G337] ;
false
```

I want some hint please cuz i don't want to  compare lengths like what they said .

Comment: The name `twice_as_long(Xs, DoubleXs)` suggests rather a different argument order. With `list__twice_as_long` it is more suggestive that the first argument is not twice as long.

Answer (score 1):

We can generalize your second example as a rule:

```
twice_as_long([_],[_,_]).
```

But we can do better:

```
twice_as_long([_|T1], [_,_|T2]) :- twice_as_long(T1,T2).
```

That, with the base case from you first example, will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to Prolog conventions, given a predicate of the form `type_of_relationship(X,Y)`, it's pretty customary to read it as a declaration of fact along the lines of

> `X` has a *type_of_relationship* with `Y`.

So, let's flip the order of the arguments: `twice_as_long(X,Y)` asserts that `X` is *twice as long* as `Y`.

Given that, and amplifying the answer from @ScottHunter, Let's break things down into simple cases.

First, your example shows a case that should fail as succeeding.

```
twice_as_long([],[]).
```

asserts that the empty list is twice as long as itself, something that is manifestly untrue: the empty list is of length zero and twice zero is still..zero. So that case should be discarded.

There is, however, the simplest case possible:

```
twice_as_long( [_,_] , [_] ) .
```

an assertion that a list of length 2 is twice as long as a list of length 1.

Then, there is the generic case:

```
twice_as_long( [_,_|Xs] , [_|Ys] ) :-
  twice_as_long(Xs,Ys) .
```

in which we say that a list of 2 or more items is twice as long as a list of 1 or more items...

**IF**, the remainder of the first list is twice as long as the remainder of the second list, where the remainders are obtained by removing the first 2 items from the first list and just 1 item from the second list.

That gives us this as the solution:

```
twice_as_long( [_]    , [_,_]    ) .
twice_as_long( [_|Xs] , [_,_|Ys] ) :- twice_as_long(Xs,Ys) .
```

The predicate will succeed when you get to the simple base case, and fail otherwise.

Comment: Although one could argue whether an empty list is twice as long as itself, I wouldn't categorize it as *manifestly untrue*. Mathematically, you've shown already that it is indeed true since twice zero (the length) is still zero.